# How to formulate questions with a compound tense?

Tags: grammaire, interrogative, temps-composés

In France is it practical to say  something like "A Janice écrit la lettre?" Or "Janice, a-t-elle écrit la lettre?". Also, can you say something like "Janice, l'a-t-elle écrit?"

Comment: Your 2nd sentence is correct and comprehensible, if you remove the comma.The first one doesn't make sense. And the last one could be correct (with an "e" at the end of *écrit*) but you need to remove the comma, and put it in a context.

Comment: Marco, please try to ask questions that can be useful to other people. When posing a question, ask yourself "Could someone by directed to this by a search engine?" Obviously google would never send anyone to a question with the title "Is it practical to say this" -- so instead this could have been titled "How to phrase interrogative questions in French?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Janice a-t-elle écrit la lettre ?**

*A Janice écrit la lettre ?* is incorrect ; subject and verb are inverted only if the subject is a pronoun. In other cases, the construction is [subject][verb]-[pronoun].

*Janice, a-t-elle écrit la lettre ?* is a bit weird : this comma doesn't make much sense.

*Janice, l'a-t-elle écrit**e** ?* (the past participle agrees with the object if the object is before the participle ; here the object is *l'[a lettre]* ad comes before *écrite*) is not something we would say or write. Topicalization (separating a subject from the rest of the sentence and repeating it with a pronoun : [Janice][...][elle]) is something you'd find in oral or colloquial French ; subject - verb inversion is more often found in written language, so this construction is a bit awkward.

Comment: So can you say "Janice a écrit la lettre?" Or "Janice elle a écrit la lettre"? How do you say "Janice wrote it" in French?

Comment: @MarcoRubenAbuyuanLlanes Janice l'a écrit(e) (add the "e" if the "it" is a feminine noun)

Comment: @cccg03 Merci! Wait, so we're my first two examples correct?

Comment: "Janice a écrit la lettre ?" is *technically* incorrect, but it's what most people would say, especially in an informal context. Don't write it though, except in really relaxed media (SMS, email). "Janice elle a écrit la lettre ?" is wrong, we don't double the subject *that* easily. In informal conversation you might say "Janice, elle a écrit la lettre" if you want to really stress that it's Janice we're talking about, but not for a question.

Comment: Informal speech: Janice a écrit la lettre? [with intonation], not incorrect for the grammar of spoken French in a specific context that has already been establshed. That's how people actually speak in some cases. They also use the written forms when speaking.

Comment: @DaWaaaaghBabal I feel like we do double the subject that easilly though. Informal Questions almost systematically have subject-doubling, it's just that the subject mostly goes at the end of the sentence (Elle a écrit la lettre, Janice?) or is prefaced by "et" if it's a new topic of conversation (Et Janice, elle a écrit la lettre?). Both feel a lot more natural to me than rising intonation with no doubling, which is an awkward mix of formal and informal.

Comment: @Eau qui dort : you're right, both your examples feel more natural. Now that I think about it, he only case where I'd use just "Janice a écrit la lettre ?" would be to express surprise / incredulity ("She did *what* ?! Who would be that stupid ?"). And yes, it seems we like double subjects a lot, I just hadn't thought about moving the name to the end.